# Can't override site address in wp-config.php for staging environment

Tags: wordpress

I created staging environment of my WP site and added the code below to `wp-config.php`(at staging env).

```
define('WP_HOME','http://staging-example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://staging-example.com');
```

I can access `http://staging-example.com/wp-admin`, however when I access http://staging-example.com, it redirects to the production url.

If I use `update_opion`, I can access `http://staging-example.com`, but I don't want to change database directly because I want production environment to use same database.

```
update_option( 'siteurl','http://staging-example.com');
update_option( 'home','http://staging-example.com');
```

Could you tell me the reason/possibilities why `define(WP_HOME...` doesn't override database values?

Comment: That's because the WP API, like `get_site_url()` uses `get_option` to retrieve the URL. If you want to know why WP was designed this way - can't tell. However, a staging system using the same DB as production somehow doesn't sound right, either. For automated staging-production sync, I'm using the wp-cli tool with `wp db export`, `wp db search-replace old-url new-url` on the SQL file and `wp db import` on the other system. This still isn't perfect since plugins requiring URL-based site keys won't work on both instances (I usually configure them for production).

Comment: Thanks, but in this specific case, we need to create environment which uses the same DB.

Comment: For overriding get_site_url() method, 

I added codes below with WP API `pre_option_{$option}`, which didn't work.




`add_filter('pre_option_siteurl', 'change_get_option_siteurl');`

```
function change_get_option_siteurl($option)
{
    if (defined('WP_SITEURL')) {
        return WP_SITEURL;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete semicolon from end of urls.

```php
define('WP_HOME','http://staging-example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://staging-example.com');
```

Comment: Oh sorry, semicolon is my mistake when I write this question. I didn't do that on staging environment.

Answer (score 0):

Because redirecting function relies on home option, adding `pre_option_home` solved this problem.
Thanks @damocres.

```
add_filter('pre_option_home', 'change_get_option_home');

function change_get_option_home($option)
{
    if (defined('WP_HOME')) {
        return WP_HOME;
    }
    return false;
}
```